# Combining of the txt files

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Within some work-dir I have several txt files with the names in a following format:

```
1.0bar_*.log
-5.0bar_*.log
-10.0bar_*.log
...
-50.0bar_*.log
```

And finally one file with the name:

```
Total_Contacts.log
```

I need simply loop the workdir and combine the containts of all of those logs into one Final_summary.log preserving the order of the information shown above.

```
for res in ${output}/*.log; do
res_tit=$(basename "$res")
res_tit=${res_tit/.log/}
# print the name of the log firstly
printf "${res_tit}" >> ${output}/Summary_Final.log
# print the containt of the res file 
# some program
# introduce space
done
```

Notice that at the beginning of the Final_summary.log I need to add a special string-marker in order to indicate the name of the file from which the contain has been taken in a format:

```
That info has been taken from the 01.0bar_*.log
# here is all of the containts of the 01.0bar_*.log

That info has been taken from the -05.0bar_*.log
# here is all of the containts of the -05.0bar_*.log


That info has been taken from the -10.0bar_*.log
# here is all of the containts of the -10.0bar_*.log

****************
And finally that is the summary from Summary_Final.log
# here is all of the containts of the Summary_Final.log
```

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: `for i in files;do echo "This is $i";cat "$i";done >summary` ?

Comment: just with echo? how I can add more flexibility here e,g in order to arrange the name of the files within the final_summary?

Comment: Yep just echo.  Echo your header, then cat your file, then echo your footer.  If you need some specific order, manage that in the definition of your list of files in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to include the name of the file as the first column:

```
for FILE in `find . -type f -name "*.log"`
do
   cat $FILE | sed 's@^@\"'$FILE'\",@g' >> Total_Contacts.log
done
```

This way you'll concatenate all the files together and have the filename being shown as the first column, it would result in something like this:

```
 01.0bar_*.log, "content of the file"
-05.0bar_*.log, "content of the file"
-10.0bar_*.log, "content of the file"
```